# smartcard PKCS#11 support on MacOSX

Tags: macos, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Does the MacOSX provide any kind of API for accessing to smartcard contents via PKCS#11 interface?

I am looking for something similar to the Smart Card API [Smart Card API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627646(v=vs.85).aspx)
provided by Windows.

Or similar to more recent
[Smart Card Minidrivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/smartcard/smart-card-minidrivers)

Comment: The link for Smart Card API is not current any more. Have a look at [Smart Card Minidrivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/smartcard/smart-card-minidrivers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from macOS 10.10 there is a specific toolkit for interacting with smartcard and token.

[CryptoTokenKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptotokenkit)

A token is a storage repository for cryptographic items. When a token is present in the system—such as when the user physically inserts a smart card into a USB slot—the CryptoTokenKit framework exposes the token’s items to your app as standard keychain items. It does this by copying the items to the keychain when the token is inserted, and deleting them from the keychain when the token is removed.

[image]